# Svelte compiler generating multiple JavaScript class definitions

Tags: svelte

I am retrofitting one of my applications from React to Svelte.

This app employs various JavaScript classes for business logic, unrelated to any GUI component representation.

I just discovered that the Svelte compiler is generating multiple renditions of these JavaScript class definitions.  From the `bundle.js`, you can see duplicate class definitions:

```js
// my original Scene class definition
class Scene extends SmartPallet { ... }
...
// a duplicate Scene class definition (generated by the Svelte compiler)
class Scene$1 extends SmartPallet { ... }
...
```

Because I am registering meta info on the class itself, these duplicate class definitions are causing a major issue, in that I cannot reliably access this meta info :-(

I have not been able to find any reference to this.  I am hoping there is a configuration option to prevent this from happening.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using these classes purely for business logic, I assume they are defined in standard `.js` files and imported into your Svelte components when needed, is that correct? Any way you could recreate a simplified version of your issue in a Svelte REPL?

Comment: Good suggestion Thomas ... I was able to isolate the problem, but would like some advice as to where to report the bug (see answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Per Thomas Hennes suggestion, I attempted to replicate this in a
simple REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/1051f1ef77c4487f938a58fd2835a5e6?version=3).
As you can imagine my domain classes are very involved, but his
suggestion made sense.  Unfortunately I was not able to replicate the
problem in this simple form.

This got me thinking that the reason I have not been able to
find anything about this issue *(I have searched "six ways from
Sunday")* is it has something to do with my environment.

Consequently, **I was able to isolate the issue!!**

The duplicate JavaScript class definitions were triggered by my usage of the
[`alias` rollup plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias).

I had configured `alias` to support "Absolute Imports".  I setup a
tilde (~) alias to reference my source root, eliminating the pain of
relative path imports.  With this configuration, **this relative import**:

```js
import Scene  from "../../../../core/Scene";
```

**could become an absolute import**:

```js
import Scene  from "~/core/Scene.js";
```

With that said, my convention was to continue to use relative imports
within a given module's directory ... e.g. **within `core`**:

```js
import Scene  from "./Scene";
```

**This was the culprit that was causing my duplicate class
definitions!!**

The **work-around solution** was to consistently use the same import
type (either relative or absolute imports), and the duplicate class
definitions disappeared.  *For now, I chose to stop using the [`alias`
rollup plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias).*

The severity of this issue will vary based on the application itself:

1. Certainly in all cases, the bundle size will be bloated (with duplicate definitions).
2. If the app relies on things like `instanceof MyClass`, it will be problematic.
3. In my case, the severity escalates to making it unusable, because my domain
   object model is somewhat advanced, utilizing package managers that are
   registering meta information directly on the class definitions ...
   which cannot be reliably accessed with the duplicate definitions.

I want to issue a "bug report" but I am unsure who the actual culprit
is ***(i.e. who is actually creating the duplicate definitions)***:

- Is it the **Svelte Compiler**? ... *I tend to think not*
- Or is it the **Rollup Bundler**? ... *I tend to think this is closer*

  - if so, is this really a bug in the [`alias` rollup plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias)

**Thoughts are welcome**!!

Thanks in advance.

`</Kevin>`

Comment: Very nice find, Kevin, and I am glad my suggestion led you to isolate, identify and remedy the issue. After digging around a little, I have found your exact issue reported here: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/296, so there is probably no need to report it any further at this stage.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for going the extra mile and sighting the rollup bug.  Your help is greatly appreciated!